# Migration tool - undeployCode - Runnning test classes?

Tags: ant

I am trying to delete some triggers from Production environment using ant migration tool. I have setup everything correctly and tested other commands like retrieveCode which work as expected.
I tried undeployCode giving proper information in destructiveChanges.xml and the command starts running test classes and is failing due to code coverage.

I have installed the latest 40 release of ant migration tool.

Can someone please help?

Comment: That is absolutely correct. Every changes around classes in production should involve passing unit tests with proper coverage

Comment: "undeployCode" does what it says, it removes code from production. To make sure that the system remains stable, the platform requires all tests to be run to make sure nothing breaks as a result of removing the code.